# Как правильно задать параметры Subplot Plotly

Tags: python, plotly

Имею такой Subplot:

```
⎡ (1,1) x,y    ⎤
⎣      :         ⎦
[ (3,1) x2,y2,y3 ]
[ (4,1) x3,y4,y5 ]
```

Графики отображаются правильно. Проблема возникает при попытке настроить параметры графиков.

В таком виде:

```
specs=[[{'rowspan': 2}],
      [None],
      [{'secondary_y': True}],     обе У оси отображаются правильно
      [{'secondary_y': True}]      обе У оси отображаются правильно
```

Проблема - параметры шаблона изменяются только в первом графике, т.е. изменить параметры во 2-ом или в 3-ем графиках не получается

В таком виде:

```
specs=[[{'secondary_y': True}],
      [None],
      [{'secondary_y': True}],   
      [{'secondary_y': True}]
```

Проблема - при таком варианте 1-ый график изображается только в первой строчке
Пробовал разные варианты, ничего не получилось

Comment: Дайте короткий но более развернутый пример кода. Определения Subplot-ов, попытка записи в графики, попытка определения параметров и что при этом конкретно не так. Из описания пока что вытянуть смысл очень проблематично.

Comment: вопрос больше не актуален, разобрался